# C++ Threads Deadlock Mutex Lock Aborted

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex, deadlock

I am trying to remove a deadlock from a program. The problem is that the program keeps giving me aborted. The point is to write data to a file. But when a deadlock occurs the thread should wait and continue later on rather than aborting.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <exception>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;

std::mutex mtx;
ofstream myfile;
condition_variable cv;

void lock()
{
  mtx.lock();
}

void unlock()
{
  mtx.unlock();
}

void writeToFile(int threadNumber){
 myfile << "[";
    for(int j =1; j <= 10; j++){
        int num = j * threadNumber;
        string line = std::to_string(num) + " ";
        myfile << line;
    }
    myfile << "]";
//mtx.unlock();
}

void threadFunction(int threadNumber)
{
//  int x = 0;
//  int y = 0;

  try{
    lock();
    if (threadNumber % 2 == 0)
      sleep(rand() % 4 + 1);
    writeToFile(threadNumber);
    throw exception();
   unlock();
  } 
  catch(...){
    cout << "Something went wrong!" << endl;
    throw exception();
  }
}


int main (int argc, char const *argv[]) {
myfile.open ("mutex.txt");
    std::set_terminate([](){
    std::cout << "Unhandled exception\n";
    // Here I want to fix the deadlock if something goes wrong. But I keep getting Abroted

    });
        int len;
        cout << "Enter Number of threads : ";
        cin >> len;
        std::thread t[len + 1];
         for(int i =1; i <= len;i++){
            t[i] = std::thread(threadFunction, i);
            cout << "Created Thread : " <<t[i].get_id()<<endl;
           }

            for(int i =1; i <= len;i++){
             t[i].join();
             }
        myfile.close();
        return 0;
}
```

Output

```
   Enter Number of threads : 5
Created Thread : 1992414288
Created Thread : 1982854224
Created Thread : 1974465616
Created Thread : 1966077008
Created Thread : 1957688400
Something went wrong!
Unhandled exception
Aborted
```

How can I avoid the aborted and let the thread wait.

Update: Included all the relevant code...

Comment: When a deadlock occurs, *all* threads concerned are blocked waiting for each other, and *none* of them can continue, *by definition*. Your question doesn't make sense. The solution to any deadlock situation is to always acquire the locks in the same order.

Comment: Do you not get a big phat warning on that `mtx.unlock()` telling you "code will never be executed." ? If not, turn up your compiler warnings.

Comment: No i do not get the warning

Comment: @johnS Switch on the `-Wall` flag when compiling.

Comment: I did but no warnings

Comment: @johnS `std::thread t[len + 1];` You should note that VLA's aren't standard C++. Use a `std::vector<std::thread>` instead. And indexing arrays in C++ goes from `0` to `N - 1` where `N` is the size of the array.

Comment: Okay thanks. Have any idea what causes it to fail?

Comment: The "Abort" failure

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure if the [`terminate_handler`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) is set for all threads. Try doing so inside the thread function.

Comment: There is no deadlock here. A deadlock requires multiple mutexes. All you have is a lock. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Answer (score 2):

Do not `lock()` / `unlock()` mutexes manually. That's error prone. Use [guards](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) instead. `mtx.unlock();` after throwing the exception won't be called.

Here's how your code should look:

```
  try{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    if (threadNumber % 2 == 0)
      sleep(rand() % 4 + 1);
    writeToFile(threadNumber);
    throw exception();
  } 
  catch(...){
    cout << "Something went wrong!" << endl;
    throw exception();
  }
```

---

To avoid deadlocks in general that locking and unlocking of multiple mutexes needs to be done in reverse order. So if one thread uses something like

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock1(mtx1);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock2(mtx2);
    // ... exception thrown somewhere
}
```

this is guaranteed since the destructors of `std::lock_guard` are guaranteed to be called in the reverse order these were constructed.

Comment: So are you saying that I cannot fix it in manually by using lock/unlock

Comment: @johnS That's not exactly what I'm saying. You may be able to call unlock in the `catch` body. That's error prone though.

Comment: I am trying to understand how it all works, hence the approach

Comment: @johnS Also note that `throw new exception();` is wrong. I have corrected that in my example.

Comment: Even if i use std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);, I still get the same output

Comment: @johnS You should provide a [MCVE] in your question. ATM it won't compile. So we have to assume that `myFile` is a global variable. Also I don't see what's unexpected with your output.

Comment: @EJP At least it avoids deadlocks for such silly reasons as placing a manual `mtx.unlock();` after throwing an exception, no? ;-)

Comment: @EJP I generalized a bit more.

Comment: The OP is wrong to have described this situation as a deadlock in the first place. It isn't.